# Is there a safer practical way to do system updates?

Tags: updates

*It scares me when I see updates with words like Crypto and RSA*, having switched to linux despite my hate for DOS (Terminal) due to CTB Locker followed by some *#*$ that was slowing taking over Windows yet no antivirus could find anything and as crazy as it sounds was even affecting my phone and car radio when it connected through bluetooth

I prefer to keep my computer updated (mainly security related) anyways, but I was wondering **is there was a more practical way** then my current method. **I keep Ubuntu installed two to three times so I can go back and forth and move files back from one to another to attempt to fix what is broke after the update** and it's not always successful. Is there a better way to undo the updates when I reboot and have no sound, when I reboot and have no network, or when I reboot and it don't boot. Right now I currently have 17.04 and amazingly it is able to connect to wifi again, I thought I was going to have to reload after that one, I also have 16.10 (I think) installed and the sound didn't work and I have tried.

**Are the updates that important?** One of the reasons I did the update to 17.04 is because 'Software' did not work after doing a previous update and when it was done I could see wireless networks but could not connect and I just copied files from 16.10 that I stopped using because sound working after a update. I assume it's just normal

Comment: Seems to me that you're overcomplicating things, and your problems are homemade. Ubuntu updates are working well for a lot of people, and even if there are occassionally bugs I don't think the problems you are experiencing are common.

Comment: If you really think having a second system available is a must to be able to revert to older version of yozur config files - consider either setting up a backup solution or a VM which can be either used as test-scenario OR as source for old file versions (whatever you prefer)

Comment: @Murphy, updates work good for some I wish I was one of them. So far I've updated and had not network, updated and had no sound which I could not fix, updated and it says unmanaged on my wired network cards, updated and it would see wireless networks and I could type in password but it wouldnt connect

Comment: @dufte. VM... didnt think of that

Comment: @JustinR have "virtual" fun ;)

Answer (score 6):

Best thing I can recommend addresses updates breaking stuff rather than your paranoia about security: Don't run the *latest* release of Ubuntu; rather, run a supported LTS version (currently 14.04 or 16.04).  I've been running Kubuntu 14.04 LTS for three years, and only twice in that time have I had to look back into an update because something significant didn't work afterward (one was a buggy kernel update, I just booted from the previous kernel, the other was having to reset X-server after an XORG update).

I still get updates several times a week, and with a supported release I'm still confident I'm as secure as Ubuntu can be (which is **far** better than Windows can be, in my opinion), but the only way stuff gets broken is if I make a boneheaded mistake -- and I make fewer of those every year I run Kubuntu.

Comment: Never thought of that. So End Of Life products still receive security updates I assume.

Comment: No, they don't, but LTS releases get five years of support.  My 14.04 will be supported until April 2019, and 16.04 will be supported until April 2021.